# Deleting rows dataframe in R conditional to "if any of (a specific variable) is equal to"

Tags: r, function, dataframe, duplicate-data

I have been struggling for some time now with this code...
I have this vector of unique ID "EID" of length 821 extracted from one of my dataframe (skate). It looks like this:

```
> head(skate$EID)
[1] "896-19" "895-8"  "899-1"  "899-5"  "899-8"  "895-7"
```

I would like to remove the complete rows in another dataframe (t5) if any of the t5$EID is equal (a duplicate) of skate$EID.

I was able to get my 'duplicated' dataframe in t5 of all my matching EID as follow:

```
> xx<-skate$EID
> t5[match(xx,t5[,26]), ]#gives me a dataframe of all matching EID in skate$EID
       record.t trip set month stratum NAFO unit.area time dur.set distance
8948          5  896  19    11     221   2J       N12  908      15        8
8849          5  895   8    10     766   3O       R36 1650      16        8
9289          5  899   1    12     743   3L       V26 2052      15        8
9299          5  899   5    12     746   3L       W27 1129      14        7
```

Where t5[,26] correspond to t5$EID column.
I'm sure it's simple, but I'm not sure how to remove all of these now from my t5 dataframe!
Tips would be very much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  To test for elements of vector A not in vector B, you can use a  combination of `!`, R's logical negation operator (see `?"!"`) and `%in%` (see `?%in%`). You then use the results of that test to indicate which rows to keep.

```
# Create two example data.frames
skate <- data.frame(EID = c("896-19", "895-8", "899-1", "899-5"), 
                    score = 1:4)
t5 <- data.frame(EID = c("896-19", "camel", "899-1", "goat", "899-1"), 
                 score = 105:101)

# Method 1
t5[!t5$EID %in% skate$EID, ] 

# Method 2 (using the very handy subset() function)
subset(t5, !EID %in% skate$EID)
```

Comment: Josh is being polite, but you should definitely click the check mark to accept an answer if your question has been answered.  It has benefits for your reputation, and it just keeps the site neat and clean to have answered answers marked as answered (say that ten times fast!).